# How to run an RFT Script in a remote machine without using RQM and RQM Adapter?

Tags: automation, rft

How to run an RFT Script in a remote machine without using RQM and RQM Adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use PSEXEC tool for that
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins to run RFT scripts on a Slave machine. Refer the link [Testing with Jenkins](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJMXE_10.0.2/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/c_jenkins.html)